# Visualforce error Not Serializable: Component.flow.interview

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, visual-workflow

i am using dynamic Visualforce component created in Apex

```
public with sharing class Sample3 {
    public Component.Flow.Interview flow{get;set;}
    public Sample3(){
    flow= new Component.Flow.Interview();
    flow.name='Calculator';     
    }
}
```

and VF page is

```
<apex:page controller="Sample3">
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!flow}"/>
</apex:page>
```

but when i open visualforce page its giving me error

> Not Serializable: Component.flow.interview

As mentioned in comment i made a demo Class and VF Page

can anyone please tell How to resolve this issue ??

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the code for your entire VF page. There may be something else missing, like a reference to your controller.

Comment: i edited my question perhaps now you can respond :)

Comment: Just like magic, see what happens when all the details are available? Keith C to the rescue with exactly the response you needed! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (attempted) serialization of the not serializable component can be avoided by making the field transient:

```
public with sharing class Sample3 {
    private transient Component.Flow.Interview flow;
    public Component.Flow.Interview getFlow() {
        return flow;
    }
    public Sample3() {
        flow = new Component.Flow.Interview();
        flow.name = 'Calculator';
    }
}
```

or simpler still by not holding the value in a field at all:

```
public with sharing class Sample3 {
    public Component.Flow.Interview getFlow() {
        Component.Flow.Interview flow = new Component.Flow.Interview();
        flow.name = 'Calculator';
        return flow;
    }
    public Sample3() {
    }
}
```

For dynamic Apex components not including the component in the view state means the components do not work fully (see e.g. [Field Values In Dynamic Component Not Retaining After Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41711/field-values-in-dynamic-component-not-retaining-after-error)); hopefully for your flow component there are no negative consequences.