# apex:dynamicComponent - Correct type of a component

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

**Situation**

I want to implement a dynamic, dynamic custom component in visualforce and apex. Therefore I created a new component:

```
<apex:component controller="SidebarController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!components}" var="component">
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!component}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

And a corresponding controller:

```
public without sharing class SidebarController
{
    public List<Component.c> components {get; set;}

    public SidebarController()
    {
        components = new List<Component.c>();

        components.add(new Component.c.TestComponent());
        components.add(new Component.c.TestComponent2());
    }
}
```

*Do you know from which type the component value has to be?*

I already tried the following types:

1. Object -> Cast fail
2. UIComponent -> Not available in apex
3. Component.c -> core.apexpages.quickfix.QuickFixException
4. Component.apex ->  core.apexpages.quickfix.QuickFixException
5. Component -> general issue

Do you know the correct type of a component in apex?

Comment: If your dynamic components will allow input, be aware of [Field Values In Dynamic Component Not Retaining After Error](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41711/field-values-in-dynamic-component-not-retaining-after-error) - the normal error handling lifecyle is broken.

Comment: Hmm ... The doc uses `Component.Apex.xxx` if the component being returned is apex.xxx; in your case, you are looking for the super class above Component.Apex.xxx - and it is not `Component.Apex` as that causes a compile error. The SFDC example similar to what you are doing enumerates each component by type explicitly and adds to the childComponents property: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm?SearchType=Stem .  `The childComponents property acts as a reference to a List of Component.Apex objects.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the correct type:

```
public List <ApexPages.Component> childComponents {get; set;}
```

[Here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_dynamic_components.htm) are the docs.

Comment: No problem. That happens to me all the time. :)